# Python Desktop Pop-Up Notification doesn't work with .pyw file

Tags: python

I wrote this python script that sends me a Desktop Notification of the current temperature, but when I save the .py file as a .pyw file, to start the script in the background, the pop up isn't working and the message only appears in the info center. Otherwise the code works just fine when I run it in the terminal or in vscode. Even when I run it with the pythonw command in the terminal it works fine. The only problem is that when I try opening it by hand, the pop up doesn't appear. I want to put the file in startup to execute it when I log in.

```
from plyer import notification
import requests
import time

temperature = None
lat = None
lon = None         #didn't want to show these variables so i cut them out temporarly
apikey = None

try:
    response = requests.get("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat={}&lon={}&appid= {}&units=metric".format(lat, lon, apikey))
    data = response.json()
except:
    print("Please! Check your internet connection")
    

notification.notify(
    title = "Today's temperature",
    message = "{}\u00B0C".format(data['main']['temp']),
    app_icon = "C:/Users/myUsername/Desktop/DailyWeather/weather.ico",
    timeout = 10,
)
```

This is my code.

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by "opening it by hand"?  `.pyw` just means the default association is to `pythonw`.  That's the only difference.  If it works when you run it with `pythonw`, then you are doing something else wrong.

Comment: When I try opening it with double click or right click and then open, the pop up message doesn't work but if I run my .py file with pythonw it works.

Comment: Do you mean, if you double-click it, NOTHING happens?  If you rename it to .py and double-click it, do you get a console window with an error?

Comment: Normaly when I double-click my .py file I get a pop-up message and the message is in my Windows Info center like intendet,  but when I double-click the .pyw file the message only appears in the windows info center without a pop-up notification on my desktop.